# Libgdx how to use shader in 3D

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, shader

I reached a point in my wip game, where I want to make it more eye-appealing. Currently I add some `Ambientlight` and a `Directionla-light` to an `Environment` and render my scene with it. But now I want to add a custom `Shader` to it. So I have been looking for some tutorials and for some reason in almost every tutorial they have used another "version" of using `Shader` in their game:

- Giving the `ModelBatch` a `String` or `FileHandle` `vertex/fragment`-shader
- Creating a `ShaderProgram` with vertex and fragment `Shader`.
- Creating a new `DefaultShader` with this vertex and fragment `Shader`.
- Creating a class, which implements `Shader` and use this `ShaderClass`.

I think there are more possibilitis, because there is also `ShaderProvider`and other classes as well.
I am a bit confused cause of all this posibilities. so I am looking for someone who can point me in the right direction.
To make it easier for you i tell you what i have and what I need:
I have:

1. A `ModelBatch` which should draw everything.
2. An `Array<ModelInstance>` instances, to which i wanna apply the `Shader`.
3. A `Texture` and its `NormalMap`, both stored as `Texture`s.
4. The `position`, the `direction` and the `color` of my light, given as `Vector3` and its strength given as `float`.
5. The `color` of the ambient light and its strength, given as `Vector3` and `float`.
6. The light "Falloff" given as `Vector3`.

I need:

1. To bind the `Texture` and its `Normal Map` to the `Shader`.
2. Give the light pos, direction, color and strength to the `Shader`.
3. Give the ambientlight color and strength to the `Shader`.
4. Give the `Falloff` Vector to the `Shader`.
5. Use this `Shader` for all "instances" in the `Array`, which are all drawn with my `ModelBatch`.

Another thing I would like to be able to do is, using different `Texture`s for different models.
I have all my `ModleInstance`s with a textured `Material`. And I have the normal map for all those different `Texture`s. Now i want to be able to bind the right `Texture` and `Normal Map` to the `Shader`, depending on the `Texture` in the `Material` of the `Modelinstance`.

A more "advanced" thing, I would like to if it is possible, is using different `Shader`s for different `ModelTypes` in my game (Stonewall uses a `Shader` without "Specularity" and "Reflection", while Metalwalls use `Specularity` for example).

What would be the best way to do this things in Libgdx?
How can i bind the different variables i have? (With ShaderProgram i can use `setUniformi` for example).

Thanks a lot. If you need more information or if it is hard to understand let me know and i will try to create a better question.

**Edit:** I think the best way in my case creating a new `Shader` class, which implements `Shader`. But i would like to hear about all the other possibilities, their pros and their cons, regarding design, performance and possible restrictions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An overall explanation of rendering pipeline of the 3d api can be found [here](http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part2/). [This tutorial](http://blog.xoppa.com/creating-a-shader-with-libgdx/) guides you in creating a new `Shader` from scratch. And [this tutorial](http://blog.xoppa.com/using-materials-with-libgdx/) show how to use custom attributes to pass data to the shader. [This wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment) also explains how to use `Material` `Attributes` and which `Attributes` the `DefaultShader` supports.

In LibGDX there's a difference between a `Shader` and `ShaderProgram`. A [`ShaderProgram`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders) is only the GPU implementation (both the vertex and fragment shader program), which is basically only the compiled GLSL files. You can, for example, set uniforms on `ShaderProgram` and use it to render a mesh. But the `ShaderProgram` itself does not "know" how it should render a model.

The `Shader` interface is intended to bridge the gap between the `ShaderProgram` and the `Renderable` (the latter being the smallest renderable part of a model). Thus a `Shader` most commonly encapsulates a `ShaderProgram` and makes sure it sets the correct uniforms etc. (Note that strictly speaking a `Shader` doesn't have to encapsulate a `ShaderProgram`. E.g. before GLES1 support was removed, there also was a GLES1 shader which managed the fixed rendering pipe instead of encapsulating a `ShaderProgram`)

The [`BaseShader`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/) class is an `abstract` helper class which implements the `Shader` interface, encapsulated a `ShaderProgram` and adds some helper methods to easily set uniforms. If you extend this class, you can easily `register` and `set` uniform, e.g. like this:

```
public class MyShader extends BaseShader {
    public final int u_falloff = register("u_falloff");
    ...
    @Override
    public void render (final Renderable renderable) {
        set(u_falloff, 15f);
        ...
        super.render(renderable);
    }
}
```

This will set the unifom called "u_falloff" to the specified value `15f` (it will call setUniformX). If the `ShaderProgram` (glsl files) don't implement an uniform called "u_falloff", it will simply ignore the call. You could also check this using: `if (has(u_falloff)) { /* calculate falloff and set it */ }`. The `BaseShader` also adds the possibility to use a `Validator` and `Setter` for each uniform.

The `DefaultShader` extends the `BaseShader` and adds a default implementation for most of the `Material` `Attributes`. Have a look [at the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/DefaultShader.java#L78) if you want to see the naming of each uniform. In practice, if you use the same uniform naming as the DefaultShader does, it is possible to only specify the glsl files and let the DefaultShader take care of setting the uniforms. Of course it is possible to extend the DefaultShader to add additional uniforms.

When you call `ModelBatch#render(...)`, the `ModelBatch` will query the `ShaderProvider` for a `Shader` to use. This is because every possible combination of vertex attributes and material attributes might require a different `Shader`. For example if you have two `ModelInstance`s (or to be more precise two `Renderable`s), one with a `TextureAttribute.Diffuse` and one without texture but with a `ColorAttribute.Diffuse`. Then most commonly, the ShaderProvider needs to create two different `Shader`s. Note that they can be of the same class (e.g. DefaultShader), but that the underlying GLSL files might be different.

The `DefaultShader` takes care of this using preprocessor macros (an ubershader). Depending on the vertex attributes and material attributes, it will `#define` multiple flags, causing the glsl program to be compiled specifically for that combination of vertex and material attributes. Have a look at [the glsl files](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders) if you want to see how this is done.

So, in practice you will likely need you own `ShaderProvider` and your own `Shader` (either by implementing it from scratch, extending `BaseShader` or extending `DefaultShader`). You can extends `DefaultShaderProvider` for this and fall back to the `DefaultShader` if needed, e.g.:

```
public class MyShaderProvider extends DefaultShaderProvider {
    ... // implement constructor
    @Override
    protected Shader createShader (final Renderable renderable) {
        if (renderable.material.has(MyCustomAttribute.Type))
            return new MyShader(renderable);
        else
            return super.createShader(renderable);
    }
}
```

tl;dr If you want to use your own or a modified version of the ubershader, using the same uniforms as the default shader does, then simply provide the glsl files. If you want to use the same uniforms but add an additional uniform or two, then it might be easy to extend DefaultShader. Otherwise (or if you're learning shaders) I would advise to create the shader from scratch as described in [This tutorial](http://blog.xoppa.com/creating-a-shader-with-libgdx/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. Yesterday i wrote my first `CustomShader`, which implements `Shader`. Now i think i will use `BaseShader`. Taking a look at the ".glsl" files you linked i have seen those `define`s. So they say the uniforms should only be defined, if they are needed? That sounds greap :P Another question to this: Do the Usage.Position, Usage.Tangent... automatically define the attributes for example `attribute vec3 a_tangent` if they are set or do i need to take care about this myself, if i extend `BaseShader`?

Comment: And one more thing: If i extend `BaseShader` and in the `canRender()` i look, if i can render this renderable and return false otherwise, doesn't the `DefaultShaderProvider` handle this then and falls back to the next `Shader`? Isn't `compareTo` used to define the `Shader` to which the `ShaderProvider` falls back if `canRender` returns false?

Comment: `BaseShader` will bind the mesh including vertex attributes (e.g. `a_tangent`) for you, just call `super.render(renderable);` at the end of the render method. Yes, have a look at `BaseShaderProvider` (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/BaseShaderProvider.java) which is what `DefaultShaderProvider` extends. `createShader` is only called, if it doesn't have a `Shader` it can reuse. `compareTo` is unrelated and used for sorting `Renderable`s (you can safely ignore it and just return `0`).

Comment: Okay so i don't need to handle the attributes myself.
Just one last thing: I have `Texture`s and their related normal map `Texture`s. I need to bind both to the `Shader`, but they can be different for every `Model`. Is there a way to give both `Texture`s to the `ModelInstance` and then pass them to the `Shader` or do i have to bind them with the `BaseShader`s `Setter` method?

Comment: Did you actually read http://blog.xoppa.com/using-materials-with-libgdx/ ? Just use TextureAttribute.Normal. See also  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment

Comment: Yea i have read them. Okay so i use `Textureatrribute.diffuse` to set my `Texture` and `TextureAttribute.Normal` to set its normal map. I feel a bit stupid now but its kind of hard to find all those things. There are so many possibilities. Thanks again. +1 and accepted!

Comment: I hope that i am not to annoying, but there is one thing in `BaseShader` i don't understand: The `init()` method takes a `Renderable` and the docu says it fetches out all attributes. But i have tons of `Renderable`s, rendered with the same `Shader` and i can `init()` only once. Do i need to give it this `Renderable` or can i just pass null, as i give the `Renderable` in the `render()` method? If not, which `Renderable` should i give it?

Comment: By using my `CustomShaderProvider` i was able to init the `CustomShader` with the right `Renderable`. But for some reason it just shows a black screen. The `ShaderProgram` itself works, as i tested them first with the default `Shader`. Is there anything i need to take care about, when i am extending `BaseShader`? I copied the code of your `Shader`tutorial and replaced the `program.setUniformX` with the `Setter` of the `BaseShader`. Also i always call super.xxx() and i let the `BaseShader` render the things, but something is wrong there...