# Effectively organizing LibGDX project with custom shader

Tags: libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I have been learning to use LibGDX and OpenGL, but I am having trouble figuring out how to implement custom shaders in a reasonable fashion.

The way I have been including shaders in my projects is to create a class that `implements` the `gdx.graphics.g3d.Shader` class. Then I use this class to compile my custom shader program and use it to render meshes.

I create my meshes by making a `ModelInstance` from a `.g3db` file, and then I pass them to the shader by calling a `ModelBatch` instance's `render()` method.

My confusion starts when I need to apply different textures for each of my meshes. Right now I am just setting a `uniform` on my shader before each `modelBatch.render()` call.

Here are my questions:

1. Is setting uniforms this way reasonable, even in a large project?
2. Is this the intended way of `implement`-ing the `Shader` class and the correct way of using OpenGl shaders in general? (Creating 1 shader and then applying it to all my models)
3. How do I use DRY principles with shaders? In other words, if I want to use a slightly different shader on a model but want to keep the same lighting as everything else. Is it best to simply include `if` statements in my shader and use a `uniform` as a flag for these special cases? Otherwise it seems I would have to create a new shader and just copy&paste most of my original shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: http://blog.xoppa.com/creating-a-shader-with-libgdx/

1. No, even more: rendering will only happen after calling `batch.end();`, so it might not produce correct results. Instead use a `Material` or `Environment` see http://blog.xoppa.com/using-materials-with-libgdx/
2. You typically would create a new shader (recompile) whenever the material changes. You can set a [`ShaderProvider`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/ShaderProvider.html) on the `ModelBatch` to manage this.
3. It depends on the use-case, but typically branching in a shader is not a good idea. Instead you can use precompiler directives to compile a different version of your shader. Have a look at the default shader and notice the `#if` directives: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/shaders/default.vertex.glsl

Comment: Your answers for 1 and 3 sound like good ideas. For 2, I am confused about how to use `ShaderProvider`. Do I need to create a new class that implements `ShaderProvider` and just return a `Shader` in `getShader()` based on the renderable's attributes? Doesn't this only work if each shader requires a unique combination of uniforms?

Comment: Yes and yes. Remember that attributes are basically the same as uniforms. Have a look at this answer where i gave a small example of using a shaderprovider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22553409/libgdx-how-to-use-shader-in-3d/22620390#22620390

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone who comes across this, you pass your `ShaderProvider` to `ModelBatch` like this: `ModelBatch batch = new ModelBatch( myShaderProvider );`